# transcend usb not auto mounting

Tags: filesystem, usb-drive, automount

I have a 16 gb transcend pen drive. One day I had partitioned into 4, and on one part I had installed ubuntu 11.04. But after that it seems the usb won't auto mount. I have used the fdisk utility and observed that my OS (ubuntu 10.04) is detecting the pen drive but not connecting to it, and making it available to my file system. I used fdisk to re-partition it, but this time I removed all partitions. Still it is not being detected by the file system (i.e. not auto-mounted)?

---

### Update 27th Jul 2011 10.47 p ist:

The usb drive was re-partitioned to have a single FAT 32 partition on which the boot flag was set. While trying to mount nautilus gave me the following error:

[image]

I'm also including the log messages in the following paste.

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=CNJrMitd

Comment: Can other USB drives be auto-mounted? How is the pen drive partitioned and formatted now?

Comment: There is now only 1 partition. Here is a paste showing details when I ran `fdisk -l` --> http://pastebin.com/5RdaCvEE

Answer (score 1):

USB drives are auto-mounted when Nautilus is set to do so. In case all USB drives fail to mount we may check if this is the case (and to enable or disable auto-mounting) by opening `gconf-editor` from a terminal and browse to *apps/nautilus/preferences*:

[image]
<sup>Default settings shown here</sup>

From there the key `media_automount` needs to be ticked in order to allow mounting an USB drive when plugged in.

---

Rarely after a failed partitioning with Gparted we may encounter a problem with a persistent policy key that was set up (but not removed) to prevent mounting of drives while partitioning. Restarting Gparted should solve this issue.

---

Mounting USB drives independent of Nautilus can also be done with [usbmount](http://packages.ubuntu.com/usbmount) [image: Install usbmount]

Comment: Other usb drives are working fine...the problem is only with this transcend usb. I can manually mount it as root user.

Comment: I don't know the significance of the first question. Boot flag - it is set to have a boot flag. Have you checked the paste? This is what you meant I hope...

Comment: okay. i've updated the question...

Comment: uhm - you know that for FAT32 the upper size limit is 4 GB?

Comment: erm, I don't know the significance of that either!

Comment: well, from what I saw you tried to partition a FAT32 to 16 GB - that may be the cause of complaints from mount... (just a guess!)

Answer (score 0):

Usb must be FAT32 to work correctly .. So after what you did, you shoud formating a new partition table too to msdos.. After this you can create a FAT partition. 
Pay attention, this procedure will erase all files on your drive.